# Angular Dependency Injection -Can't Instantiate Factory/ Undefined Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have completely stumped myself with trying to instantiate a factory in my controller. No matter what I do it seems my factory ('FBRetrieve') is undefined. It must be something very simple, but can't seem to find a solution via S/O search/google/angulardocs.

app.js

```
var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc', ['ngRoute','FireBaseService']);
```

factory.js

```
angular.module("FireBaseService", []).factory('FBRetrieve', function(){
    var biblioData = new Object();


    biblioData.getData = function(type){
        var biblioRef = new Firebase('https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com/'+type);

        biblioRef.on('value', function(data) {
            if (data.val() === null) {
                console.log("ERROR");
                return;
            }
            console.log(data.val());
            biblioData = data.val();


        });

        return biblioData;

    };

});
```

and in the controller I'm instantiating with something like this:

```
legalmvc.controller('FormCtrl',["$scope","FBRetrieve", function ($scope, FBRetrieve) {

    $scope.FBRetrieve = FBRetrieve.getData('case');

.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getData` is asynchronous operation, it means that response is not yet available when you try to return it. Instead you should use callback of deferred pattern (more natural in this case):

```
biblioData.getData = function(type) {

    var biblioRef = new Firebase('https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com/'+type),
        deferred = $q.defer(); // remember to inject $q service into factory 

    biblioRef.on('value', function(data) {
        if (data.val() === null) {
            deferred.reject('ERROR');
        }
        deferred.resolve(data.val());
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then you would use it in controller:

```
FBRetrieve.getData('case').then(function(data) {
    $scope.FBRetrieve = data;
}, function() {
    // handle error
});
```

Also learn about this common [problem and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/949476).